# Create new cell in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to create a new cell in a table view controller. The problem I am having is basically that I need to control what the cell will show in the right and left text (the style of the cell is "Right Detail"). I would like saved.text to be displayed in the right and savedName.text to be displayed in the left. The code that creates a new cell should be in the AccessData void. Hope you guys have an idea on how to do this.

Here's a little more background on the code:

I basically have a number generator which generates a random number and I have a button which saves that number. So when the user presses the save button, the user will be presented with a screen showing a text input where the user can input a title. Then when the done button is pressed, the title and random number will be saved in a table view as a new cell. The title will be shown to the left in the cell and the random number will be shown to the right. I will probably need to use arrays a lot more than what I have done already but this is basically what is going on. I have all the code for the number generator working but I just need the save and table view code set up. Hope you guys have an idea on how to make this work.

.h file

```
NSString *saved;     
NSString *savedName;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UILabel *display2;
IBOutlet UILabel *displayName;
NSMutableArray *list;
}

-(void)AccessData:(id)sender;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hej", nil];

}

-(void)AccessData:(id)sender {
if (savedData == 1) {
    savedName = displayName.text;
}

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [list count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier ];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: Why not just subclass UITableViewCell and add two labels in the positions that you want?

Comment: I dont undertand what is not working for you, elaborate on what is not working as expected

Comment: I need to create a new cell in the table view as described before but I need to use two NSStrings as the text being displayed in the cell. How would I do this? It's basically just how to create a cell and change the title (and detail) in the cell to two different NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `reloadData` on your table whenever your model changes. Your model in this case is your `list` array.